# Moving large amounts of data instead of updating it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large table (about 40M Rows) where I had a number of columns that are 0 which need to be null instead so we can better key the data.

I've written scripts to look chop the update into chunks of 10000 records, find the occurance of the columns with zero and update them to null.

Example:

```
update FooTable
set    order_id = case when order_id = 0 then null else order_id end,
       person_id = case when person_id = 0 then null else person_id end 
WHERE  person_id = 0
OR     order_id = 0
```

This works great, but it takes for ever.

I thinking the better way to do this would be to create a second table and insert the data into it and then rename it to replace the old table with the columns having zero.

Question is - can I do a insert into table2 select from table1 and in the process cleanse the data from table1 before it goes in?

Comment: What are the indexes you've created on `FooTable` ? Have you considered splitting the SQL into two SQL (one for `WHERE person_id = 0` and another for `WHERE order_id = 0`)? Have you looked at execution plans?

Answer (score 0):

You can usually create a new, sanitised, table, depending on the actual DB server you are using.

The hard thing is that if there are other tables in the database, you may have issues with foreign keys, indexes, etc which will refer to the original table.

Whether making a new sanitised table will be quicker than updating your existing table is something you can only tell by trying it.

Comment: Actually just tried it and worked like a charm!

Was able to perform the mass insert into a new table in just over 3 minutes whereas the update was taking 10+ hours.

Ended up looking like this:

INSERT FooTable2 (order_id, person_id) SELECT case when order_id = 0 then null else order_id end, case when person_id = 0 then null else person_id end time_stamp FROM FooTable

Now, I will have to go back and drop the keys and indexes from FooTable, Drop FooTable, Rename FooTable2 and then create the indexes and such but thats better than waiting around.

Answer (score 0):

Dump the pk/clustered key of all the records you want to update into a temp table. Then perform the update joining to the temp table. That will ensure the lowest locking level and quickest access. You can also add an identity column to the temp table, than you can loop through and do the updates in batches.